# A Lie group whose Lie algebra is the (Lie algebra?) of all functions with fibrewise polynomial growth

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let  $M$ be  a Riemannian  manifold. We denote by $\mathfrak{g}$ the space of  all smooth function $f:TM\to \mathbb{R}$  with fibre wise polynomial growth. Is it a Lie  algebra wrt the Poisson bracket on symplectic manifold $TM$? What is a precise infinite dimensional Lie group whose  Lie  algebra is the above $\mathfrak{g}$?
Is the isomorphism class of Lie  algebra  mentioned above independent of choosing Riemanian metric?